# Sail npm run dev

Tags: docker, vue.js, sails.js, inertiajs, laravel-10

I'm new to Laravel, My application is Laravel, Vue + InertiaJS.
I start my docker in terminal with

```
sail up -d
```

This will start the docker container, then I navigate to the url of my application,
when I type in the terminal

```
sail npm run dev
```

that supposedly run the the backend and frontend of my app, but if I check in the browser it only shows me white empty page.
but when I execute the command

```
sail npm run build
```

it will start to build the app, in this way, the app will work fine,

my problem is everytime I make changes I have to do the *sail npm run build*, and it consumes a lot of time in building the project, is there anyway can fix this?. That I only execute command *sail npm run dev*, and it should be working just like *sail npm run build* and no need for me to build again if I change something in the code

docker.compose.yml

```
build:
        context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.2
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
        args:
            WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
    image: sail-8.2/app
    extra_hosts:
        - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
    ports:
        - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
    environment:
        WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
        LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
        XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        IGNITION_LOCAL_SITES_PATH: '${PWD}'
    volumes:
        - '.:/var/www/html'
        - './library/petcheckr-library/resources/js:/var/www/html/resources/js/Petcheckr'
        - './library/xocdr-library/resources/js:/var/www/html/resources/js/Xocdr'
        - './storage/app/public:/var/www/html/public/storage'
    networks:
        - petcheckr
    depends_on:
        - mariadb
        - redis
        - mailpit
mariadb:
    image: 'mariadb:10'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
        MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    volumes:
        - 'sail-mariadb:/var/lib/mysql'
        - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
    networks:
```

Comment: In your docker-compose.yml make sure you expose the port for Vite, so publish docker-compose.yml and edit that file, look for 'vite' and make sure during the build that vite port is available, etc

Comment: @UnderDog I edit my post, I docker.compose.yml. Can you please elaborate more?. Thank you

Comment: This is a tough one to anser, but ok (always keep updating your original question with this extra information) ... in your vite.config.js, did you do anything special? Are you using vue? Since that could also give a blank page. In your view file, where you call `@vite`, which .css file are you calling there? is it still `@vite('resources/css/app.css')`?